# Gridview database not being updated on selection of a new value in the current row's dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, oracle, gridview

I have a gridview with four columns. The first three are bound fields (STARTENDYEAR, ENDYEAR and IDENTIFIER) and the third is a dropdown(CHANGE). The purpose of the dropdown is to change the value of the IDENTIFIER field. The first three columns are fetched from one oracle table. Each STARTENDYEAR has a list of IDENTIFIER values applicable to it. These applicable values are available in a different table. These values have been fetched and been populated in the dropdown successfully. I am using ASP.NET with C#

**Requirement** : Whenever the user selects a different value from the dropdown, the gridview and backend table need to be updated with the new IDENTIFIER value.

**Implemented so far**: The dropdown has been populated with the list of applicable values from the second table. Whenever the user selects a new value, I'm able to capture the new value at the backend code.

**Issue** : Unable to update the gridview and database with the new IDENTIFIER value fetched. I suspect it might be a databinding issue which is preventing the sql update query from firing successfully at the backend C# code.

**ASP Code:**

```
<%@ Page Title="Database" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"    AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="Database.aspx.cs" Inherits="About" %>

 <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
 </asp:Content>
 <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
 DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound1" DataKeyNames="IDENTIFIER">
        <Columns>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="STARTENDYEAR" HeaderText="STARTENDYEAR" 
                SortExpression="STARTENDYEAR" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ENDYEAR" HeaderText="ENDYEAR" SortExpression="ENDYEAR" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="IDENTIFIER" HeaderText="IDENTIFIER" 
                SortExpression="IDENTIFIER" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CHANGE" SortExpression="CHANGE"> 
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataTextField="CODE" DataValueField="CODE" 
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True"> 
                    </asp:DropDownList> 
                </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField> 
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RonSql %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RonSql.ProviderName %>"
    SelectCommand="select STARTENDYEAR, ENDYEAR, IDENTIFIER from R70A109 where (STATE = :SegState) order by STARTENDYEAR, ENDYEAR">

         <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="SegState" SessionField="SegState" DefaultValue="0" />

         </SelectParameters>               


    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RonSql %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RonSql.ProviderName %>"> 


    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**C# CODE:**

```
public partial class About : System.Web.UI.Page
{
        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {          DataRowView CurrentRow = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
         if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
         {
             int StartYear = Convert.ToInt32(CurrentRow["StartYear"].ToString());

        if (StartYear > 2005)
            StartYear = 2005;

            DataTable dtcodes = GetByState(StartYear);

            DropDownList CurrentDropDown = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1");
            CurrentDropDown.DataSource = dtcodes;
            CurrentDropDown.DataBind();

    }
}




 protected void DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   DropDownList SelectedDropDown = (DropDownList)sender;
   GridViewRow SelectedRow = (GridViewRow)SelectedDropDown.NamingContainer;
   int StartYear = Convert.ToInt32(SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text);
   int EndYear = Convert.ToInt32(SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
   int IdentifierOld = Convert.ToInt32(SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text);
   int IdentifierNew =  Convert.ToInt32(SelectedDropDown.SelectedItem.Value);


   if (StartYear < 2005)
   {
       string ConString = "Data Source=ORACLE;User ID=****;Password=****";
       string CodeUpdate = "update R70A109 set IDENTIFIER = :New_Identifier where StartYear = :StartYear) AND (EndYear = :EndYear) AND (IDENTIFIER = :Old_Identifier)";
       OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConString);
       con.Open();
       OracleCommand SqlCodeUpdate = new OracleCommand(CodeUpdate, con);
       SqlCodeUpdate.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@New_Identifier", IdentifierNew));
       SqlCodeUpdate.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@StartYear", StartYear));
       SqlCodeUpdate.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@EndYear", EndYear));
       SqlCodeUpdate.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@Old_Identifier", IdentifierOld));
       OracleDataAdapter DatAdpt = new OracleDataAdapter();
       DatAdpt.UpdateCommand = SqlCodeUpdate;
        con.Close();

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You must call ExecuteNonQuery on OracleCommand object to execute the instruction in base.

....

```
if (StartYear < 2005)
   {
       string ConString = "Data Source=ORACLE;User ID=****;Password=****";
       string CodeUpdate = "update R70A109 set IDENTIFIER = :New_Identifier where StartYear = :StartYear) AND (EndYear = :EndYear) AND (IDENTIFIER = :Old_Identifier)";
       using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConString))
       {
            OracleCommand SqlCodeUpdate = new OracleCommand(CodeUpdate, con);
            SqlCodeUpdate.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@New_Identifier", IdentifierNew));
            SqlCodeUpdate.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@StartYear", StartYear));
            SqlCodeUpdate.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@EndYear", EndYear));
            SqlCodeUpdate.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@Old_Identifier", IdentifierOld));
            SqlCodeUpdate.Connection.Open();
            SqlCodeUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }

    }
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I face an issue while running the webpage using the modifications suggested. After i select a different value from the dropdown, the webpage says "Waiting for localhost" for a long time. And i don't get the gridview and database updated.

Comment: There have much reasons for this results. Have you place a break point on DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged method ?

Answer (score 0):

**FOUND A WAY** 
I faced the same problem, that I have a dropdown in the edit template field of gridview. The value change in the dropdown doesn't affect during update. I have solved it by the following steps. 1. Check the value returned by the dropdown in the 'RowUpdating' event.(That should be the exact value of dropdown you have selected)

Find and change the value of field with the value from the dropdown. Thats it... For instance, the row updating event is as below..
`protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e) 
{

DropDownList dr = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("DropYearEdit"); string st = dr.SelectedValue;
string sr = dr.SelectedItem.Text;

// Manually change the inner value of required field 
e.NewValues["year"] = st; 
}`

Now the changed value is going to the database..